# VS 2017 and Microsoft Cognitive Toolkit 2.0 RC3 (CNTK)

Tags: cntk

Can I compile **Microsoft Cognitive Toolkit 2.0** RC3 (CNTK) with **VS 2017** Preview?

Answer (score 1):

VS2017 does not work.

CNTK needs VS2015 update 3.
2015-1 or 2 also does not work.

Installation takes time so better to check.
To check Visual studio version
click Help => About Visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anyone has tried. It's probably OK, except if you want to compile the GPU stuff. Nvidia is currently not listing Visual Studio 2017 as a supported platform.

Comment: It does for **CUDA 9**.
I am waiting for CNTK 2.3 that will compile with **VS 2017**, finally as promised.

Comment: In the context of an answer posted on May 30th 2017 "currently" means "at that time". Cuda 9 was released sometime in September 2017.